# How to navigate in jetpack compose to another screen without this problem?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a problem with navigating to another screen in Jetpack compose. I have everything set up, everything double-checked, and still, when I push the button it should bring to another screen. I get a few debug info in logcat, which indicates that something did go wrong with the navigation and nothing will happen. When I tried to figure out the problem I found out that the function that should represent the second screen is successfully called and when I use the function Log.d("Second screen") it will be printed in the log cat successfully. Still, none of the content will appear and none of the previous content will disappear. I tried to google it and also asked chat gpt, but I didn't find anything, and chat gpt only told me that it should work fine and I should check everything once again. In the end, I created a new project and put my code in there thinking that it might be some project setting, which is causing the problem, but nothing changed.

Here is my Main_activity. There is set up everything to navigation and the button that should initiate it:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ToDoApp2Theme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.HomeScreen.route) {
                    composable(route = Screens.HomeScreen.route){ Greeting(navController) }
                    composable(route = Screens.AddScreen.route){ Add_screen(navController) }
                }
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting(navController)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(navController: NavController, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .width(15.dp)
        .height(20.dp)
        .padding(vertical = 100.dp, horizontal = 100.dp)){
        Button(onClick = {
            navController.navigate(Screens.AddScreen.route)
        }) {
            Text(text = "+")
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ToDoApp2Theme {
        val navController = rememberNavController()
        Greeting(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

Screens:

```
package com.example.todoapp2

sealed class Screens(val route: String){
    object HomeScreen : Screens("Greeting")
    object AddScreen : Screens("AddScreen")
}
```

AddScreen:

```
package com.example.todoapp2

import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.navigation.NavController

@Composable
fun Add_screen(navController: NavController) {
    Text(text = "this is my add screen")
}
```

I have implemented the navigation at the newest version: 2.7.4. I have no errors in the app.
The debug in the logcat which I think should be related to this is: nav gesture mode swipeFromBottom ignore true downX 63 downY 1591 mScreenHeight 1600 mScreenWidth 720
The values for downX and downY are changing each time. It is written every time I push the button. I am new to jetpack compose and I am out of options that could solve this. Please anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Surface` you have in your `ToDoApp2Theme` and only have the `NavHost`?

Comment: I don't really understand why, but you are right. I deleted Surface and it started working. I wouldn't expect that it could be caused by that at all. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

A `NavHost` is what displays the screens of your app. By adding another `Surface` with a solid color, you've effectively hidden the actual `NavHost` entirely with **another copy** of your `Greeting` screen - one that also hides any changes in the `NavHost`.

So just remove the other `Surface` entirely and you'll only see your `NavHost` and the screens it swaps between when you call `navigate`.